# Is there a way to do DrawingContext.DrawImage by specifying a subregion of the source rectangle?

Tags: wpf, drawimage

In WPF, DrawingContext.DrawImage looks like this:

```
public abstract void DrawImage(
    ImageSource imageSource,
    Rect rectangle
)
```

The rectangle is documented as "The region in which to draw `BitmapSource`."

I need a way to draw a sub-rectangle of the source rectangle into the destination rectangle.

In WinForms, you can do this easily because Graphics.DrawImage takes two rectangles. For example,

```
public void DrawImage(
    Image image,
    Rectangle destRect,
    int srcX,
    int srcY,
    int srcWidth,
    int srcHeight,
    GraphicsUnit srcUnit
)
```

In WPF, I don't see any equivalent.

Anyone have a clean and performant way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may draw a `CroppedBitmap`:

```
ImageSource source = ...
var sourceRect = new Int32Rect(...);
var croppedBitmap = new CroppedBitmap(source, sourceRect);
...
drawingContext.DrawImage(croppedBitmap, new Rect(...));
```